# PHP converting JSON file into excel table is formatted incorrectly

Tags: php, json, excel

#### I have made a PHP file that takes this *JSON-based* file:

http://www.yellowpages.com.iq/ajax/get/register/Categories.php 
and converts it into an excel-formatted-table with the formatting of (.cvs) using this code :

---

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.yellowpages.com.iq/ajax/get/register/Categories.php');

$data = JSON_decode($contents);
$excel_file = fopen("file.csv", "a+");
$table = "<table border='1'>";
foreach($data as $elem) {
    $table .= "<tr>";
    foreach($elem as $key => $prop) {
        $table .= "<th>$key</th>";
        $table .= "<td>$prop</td>";
        fwrite($excel_file, "$key,$prop\n");
    }
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "</table>";
echo $table;
```

But the problem being, is it takes the data and displays it correctly, although it tends to format it like so: 
id   1
category    Advertising
id  2
category    Agriculture & FoodÂ
id  3
category    Air condition
id  4
category    Airlines
id  5
Aluminium & Glass

#### Instead of what I'm trying to make it look like which I made manually:

[image: Correct Formatting] 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: CSV is a simple format, but it still has its corner cases (embedded commas, quotation marks, etc) that mean you can't just blindly output a string into a CSV file without examining it.  You should really use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead of doing it manually (e.g. `fputcsv($excel_file, array($key, $prop));`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the code using `fputcsv`, which takes care of double quotes and escaping them.

For that you need to get the JSON as an associative array (provide the second argument `true`):

```
$data = JSON_decode($contents, true);
```

And then the loop you have would be replaced with this:

```
// "loop" for the header (only 1 iteration)
foreach($data as $elem) {
    $table .= "<tr><th>" . implode("</th><th>", array_keys($elem)) . "</th></tr>";
    fputcsv($excel_file, array_keys($elem));
    break; // only need one row for header
}
// Restart loop for the data
foreach($data as $elem) {
    $table .= "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $elem) . "</td></tr>";
    fputcsv($excel_file, $elem);
}
```